# create-react-app crashes after new deployment

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I use "GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false react-scripts build" to build the file and deploy it on Azure.

When the previous version is active on the browser for some client the react app crashes when the new js file is trying to be loaded.

I can see that main.[hash].chunk.js file name has changed causing this to happen.

Once the page is refreshed it is all good and works fine.

Is there a neat way of handling it other than storing the version number, increment it and doing a window.location.reload based on the version number?

Comment: i guess a simple restart should work.

Comment: Yes client refreshing the page works. But what if they are in the middle of something and it crashes. So wondering if there is a neat way.

Comment: I'm facing the same problem. Did you find any solution?

Comment: Also, could you please describe the `storing the version number, increment it and doing a window.location.reload based on the version number` more detailed? How should it look in terms of code?

Comment: @evisotskiy Are you using lazy loading code split components in your app? I can answer based on that. 

Sorry window.location.reload method is an indirect way by adding websockets to check if the version has changed. So ignore that!

Comment: @evisotskiy You can use something like this. 
 const LazyLoadedHomeComponent = React.lazy(() => import(/* webpackPrefetch: true * /'./src/Home'));

What happens is the lazy loaded component is fetched in the background when network request is idle. Therefore it wont look for the old chunk file from the server which will be changed during every build if something within it changes. Also when the user refreshes the page, all of the new js files are updated so that it never crashes.

Comment: @stevevar great example for lazy loading, thanks! But currently I don't use lazy loading, and the issue appears for static js files. Still cannot find a solution for them

Comment: @evisotskiy If you dont have any lazy loading components and you have used Create-React-App then you should have only two major js files. main.[hash].chunk.js (This is your components all bundled into one) and another [number].[hash].chunk.js (This is you nodemodules bundled into one). There will be another runtime-main.[hash].js and [number].[hash].chunk.js (webpack server) which you can ignore. Can you check if there are more than 4 js files in build/static/js folder? If there is then check the map to identify which component is generating other static file?

Comment: @evisotskiy Refer to this https://create-react-app.dev/docs/production-build and check your build/static/js folder. Those vendor [number].[hash].chunk.js and main js main.[hash].chunk.js files are loaded at the start you can check it in network tab.